# Memory efficency of defaultdict

Tags: python

I was trying some examples for calculating PMI, trying to calculate for some tweet messages i had (collection of ~50k), if found out that the bottleneck of the implementation of the [algorithm](http://marcobonzanini.com/2015/05/17/mining-twitter-data-with-python-part-6-sentiment-analysis-basics/) was in the `defaultdict(lambda : defaultdict(int))`, and i don't know why:

Here is the example where i profiled it and was taking a lot of memory and time

```
for term, n in p_t.items():
    positive_assoc = sum(pmi[term][tx] for tx in positive_vocab)
    negative_assoc = sum(pmi[term][tx] for tx in negative_vocab)
    semantic_orientation[term] = positive_assoc - negative_assoc
```

where the part:

```
positive_assoc = sum(pmi[term][tx] for tx in positive_vocab)
negative_assoc = sum(pmi[term][tx] for tx in negative_vocab)
```

allocates a lot of memory for some reason. I am assuming that for the values that are doesn't exist returns 0, so the array passed to the *sum* function is pretty big.

I solved the problem with simple `if value exist` and a variable `sum_pos`.

The whole implementation from the blog:

```
pmi = defaultdict(lambda : defaultdict(int))
for t1 in p_t:
    for t2 in com[t1]:
        denom = p_t[t1] * p_t[t2]
        pmi[t1][t2] = math.log2(p_t_com[t1][t2] / denom)

semantic_orientation = {}
for term, n in p_t.items():
    positive_assoc = sum(pmi[term][tx] for tx in positive_vocab)
    negative_assoc = sum(pmi[term][tx] for tx in negative_vocab)
    semantic_orientation[term] = positive_assoc - negative_assoc
```

Comment: Which thing here is the `defaultdict`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`defaultdict` will call the factory function for each and every key that is missing. If you are using it in a `sum()` where there are a lot of keys missing you will indeed create a whole load of dictionaries that grow to contain more keys without you using them.

Switch to using the [`dict.get()` method](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) here to prevent the objects being created:

```
positive_assoc = sum(pmi.get(term, {}).get(tx, 0) for tx in positive_vocab)
negative_assoc = sum(pmi.get(term, {}).get(tx, 0) for tx in negative_vocab)
```

Note that the `pmi.get()` call returns an empty dictionary, so that the chained `dict.get()` call continues to work and can return the default `0` if there is no dictionary associated with the given `term`.

Comment: Thanks. Good to know this kind of stuff.

Answer (score 1):

I like Martjin's answer... but this should also work, and you might find it more readable.

`positive_assoc = sum(pmi[term][tx] for tx in positive_vocab if term in pmi and 
                     tx in pmi[term)
negative_assoc = sum(pmi[term][tx] for tx in negative_vocab if term in pmi and 
                     tx in pmi[term)`